# Structuring test code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute

Currently we are trying to implement some unittesting on our services. In the below service an order is created and a audit registration is made about the creation of an order. When writing the two tests (because we think the tests should be seperated to get tests with 1 responsibility) this was where I started with:

```
public class TestPacklineOrderManagementService
{

    [Fact]
    public void CreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
    {

        IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineOrderRepository>();
        packLineOrderRepository.GetActive(Arg.Any<PackLine>()).Returns(x => null);
        var rawProductRepository = Substitute.For<IRawProductRepository>();
        rawProductRepository.Get(1).Returns(new RawProduct {Id = 1});
        var packlineRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineRepository>();
        packlineRepository.Get(1).Returns(new PackLine {Id = 1});
        var auditRegistrationService = Substitute.For<IAuditRegistrationService>();
        var packlineOrderManagementService = new PacklineOrderManagementService(packLineOrderRepository, rawProductRepository, packlineRepository, auditRegistrationService);

        packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1,1);

        packLineOrderRepository.Received()
            .Insert(Arg.Is<PackLineOrder>(x => x.PackLine.Id == 1 && x.Product.Id == 1));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AuditCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
    {
        IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineOrderRepository>();
        packLineOrderRepository.GetActive(Arg.Any<PackLine>()).Returns(x=>null);
        var rawProductRepository = Substitute.For<IRawProductRepository>();
        rawProductRepository.Get(1).Returns(new RawProduct { Id = 1 });
        var packlineRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineRepository>();
        packlineRepository.Get(1).Returns(new PackLine { Id = 1 });
        var auditRegistrationService = Substitute.For<IAuditRegistrationService>();
        var packlineOrderManagementService = new PacklineOrderManagementService(packLineOrderRepository, rawProductRepository, packlineRepository, auditRegistrationService);

        packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1, 1);

        auditRegistrationService.Received()
            .Audit(Arg.Is<PackLineOrderAudit>(item => item.Action == PackLineOrderAction.CreatePacklineOrder));
    }
}
```

As you can see a lot of duplicate code. To prevent this I tried to refactor this and it resulted in the code below:

```
public class TestPacklineOrderManagementService2
{

    [Fact]
    public void CreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
    {
        IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository;
        IAuditRegistrationService auditRegistrationService;
        var packlineOrderManagementService = BuilderForCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable(out packLineOrderRepository, out auditRegistrationService);

        packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1,1);

        packLineOrderRepository.Received().Insert(Arg.Any<PackLineOrder>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AuditCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
    {
        IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository;
        IAuditRegistrationService auditRegistrationService;
        var packlineOrderManagementService = BuilderForCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable(out packLineOrderRepository, out auditRegistrationService);

        packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1, 1);

        auditRegistrationService.Received()
            .Audit(Arg.Is<PackLineOrderAudit>(item => item.Action == PackLineOrderAction.CreatePacklineOrder));
    }

    private PacklineOrderManagementService BuilderForCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable(out IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository,
       out IAuditRegistrationService auditRegistrationService)
    {
        packLineOrderRepository = CreatePackLineOrderRepository(x => null);
        auditRegistrationService = CreateAuditRegistrationService();

        var rawProductRepository = CreateRawProductRepository(x => new RawProduct { Id = 1 });
        var packlineRepository = CreatePacklineRepository(x => new PackLine { Id = 1 });
        var packlineOrderManagementService = new PacklineOrderManagementService(packLineOrderRepository,
            rawProductRepository, packlineRepository, auditRegistrationService);

        return packlineOrderManagementService;
    }

    private IPackLineOrderRepository CreatePackLineOrderRepository(Func<CallInfo, PackLineOrder> getActiveResult)
    {
        IPackLineOrderRepository packLineOrderRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineOrderRepository>();
        packLineOrderRepository.GetActive(Arg.Any<PackLine>()).Returns(getActiveResult);
        return packLineOrderRepository;
    }

    private IRawProductRepository CreateRawProductRepository(Func<CallInfo, RawProduct> getResult)
    {
        IRawProductRepository rawProductRepository = Substitute.For<IRawProductRepository>();
        rawProductRepository.Get(1).Returns(getResult);
        return rawProductRepository;
    }

    private IPackLineRepository CreatePacklineRepository(Func<CallInfo, PackLine> getResult)
    {
        IPackLineRepository packLineRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineRepository>();
        packLineRepository.Get(1).Returns(getResult);
        return packLineRepository;
    }

    private IAuditRegistrationService CreateAuditRegistrationService()
    {
        return Substitute.For<IAuditRegistrationService>();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get a better code base for our unittests?

Comment: I think that this question might be better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

*Better* is very subjective, it depends a lot on how you define it.  Some people might argue that your first example was better since all of the setup code is together in your test. I do have some feedback based on your code above though...

When you're writing tests, don't use the same value for two parameters to your system under test (SUT) unless they really are the same, it hides transposition errors.  So, in your test, you're setting up one of your substitutes like this:

```
rawProductRepository.Get(1).Returns(new RawProduct {Id = 1});
```

Then calling your SUT:

```
packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1,1);
```

Are the 1s in the SUT call related to the Repository setup?  It's not at all clear which 1 is which...

This somewhat subjective, but if your test setup is *exactly* the same, do you really need to duplicate the test, with different asserts?  Does it *really* make sense for the `Audit` to take place if the `Insert` hasn't etc?

If you do have groups of tests that have similar setups, then you could push the common bits into your classes constructor.  You could also organise your tests using nested classes, something like this:

```
public class TestPacklineOrderManagementService
{
    public class TestSetProduct {
        IPackLineOrderRepository _packLineOrderRepository;
        IRawProductRepository _rawProductRepository;
        // etc
        public TestSetProduct() {
            _packLineOrderRepository = Substitute.For<IPackLineOrderRepository>();
            _packLineOrderRepository.GetActive(Arg.Any<PackLine>()).Returns(x => null);
            _rawProductRepository = Substitute.For<IRawProductRepository>();
            // etc
        }
        [Fact]
        public void CreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
        {
            // Any test specific setup...               

            _packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1,1);

            _packLineOrderRepository.Received()
                .Insert(Arg.Is<PackLineOrder>(x => x.PackLine.Id == 1 
                                                && x.Product.Id == 1));
        }       
        [Fact]
        public void AuditCreateNewProductWhenNoPacklineOrderIsAvailable()
        {
            _packlineOrderManagementService.SetProduct(1, 1);

            _auditRegistrationService.Received()
                .Audit(Arg.Is<PackLineOrderAudit>(item => 
                               item.Action == PackLineOrderAction.CreatePacklineOrder));
        }
    }
    public class TestSomeOtherScenario {
        // tests...
    }
}
```

This approach and make your tests more succinct and easier to follow, if they only contain the test specific information, but is it better?  It's very subjective, some people ([including the xunit team](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons#note2)) don't like shared per test setups.  Really it's about finding the approach that works for you and your team...